# jQuery this and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting jQuery `this` and loop in this function.

In this function `.expandIcon` class is used multiple times, but no loops here so how does it work? Also please explain 'this'.

```
$('.expandIcon').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("bi-dash-circle bi-plus-circle");
  console.log(this);
  $(this).closest(".faq-heading").children(".faq-answer").toggleClass("d-none");
})
```

i am getting right answer but not understanding code.

Comment: That's what jQuery does. `$('.expandIcon').click()` means to attach a "click" handler to every matching element.

Comment: [RTM](https://api.jquery.com/click/) please

Answer (score 1):

JQuery 'wraps' the element(s) into a (special) `Array` and the handler function is assigned to every element of that.

If the handler is a function expression (not an arrow function) than `this` is actually the target of the event (aka `[event].target`).

The snippet demonstrates that.

```js
$('.expandIcon').click( function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`Hi, you CLICKED ${this.outerHTML}`);
  console.log(`[this] equals [e.target]? ${
    this === e.target ? `yep` : `nope`}`);
  // Note: [this] is a native element. 
  // You don't need to wrap it (using $(this)) 
  // to find the closest [element].faq-heading
  console.log(this.closest(`.faq-heading`));
});

// plain js equivalent for 'mouseover'
document.querySelectorAll('.expandIcon')
  .forEach( el => 
    el.addEventListener(`mouseover`, function(e) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(`Hi, you HOVERED: ${this.outerHTML}`);
      console.log(this.closest(`.faq-heading`));
  }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-heading">
  <div class="expandIcon">div.expandIcon 1</div>
  <div class="expandIcon">div.expandIcon 2</div>
  <div class="expandIcon">div.expandIcon 3</div>
</div>
```